# Select set of results (filter) using composite key ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have a table of this nature, `Year` and `Month` creates a composite key together.

```
+------+-------+------------------+------------------+
| Year | Month | Numeric Column 1 | Numeric Column 2 |
+------+-------+------------------+------------------+
| 2016 |    12 |              455 |            56600 | <
| 2017 |    11 |            10.56 |            98000 |
| 2017 |    12 |             45.2 |          56422.5 | <
| 2018 |     1 |              550 |            12200 |
| 2018 |     2 |              440 |            52000 |
| 2018 |     3 |                0 |               11 |
| 2018 |     4 |                0 |               11 |
| 2019 |     1 |              123 |             4200 |
+------+-------+------------------+------------------+
```

What I want to do is simple, select a subset of rows which complies to a request like,

```
?startyear=2016&endyear=2019&startmonth=1&endmonth=11
```

I have ordered this table by `Year` and by `Month`, then I apply the filter as follows.

```
IQueryable<Balance> reportToReturn = _context.Balances.OrderBy(b => b.Year).ThenBy(b => b.Month).AsQueryable();
reportToReturn = reportToReturn.Where(b => b.Year >= report.StartYear && b.Year <= report.EndYear);
reportToReturn = reportToReturn.Where(b => b.Month >= report.StartMonth && b.Month <= report.EndMonth);
List<Balance> result = reportToReturn.ToList();
```

What happens is after it gets correspoding results to the provided `Year` range, when it's filtered by `Month`, as an example if I provide above query, 12th month of 2016 and 2017 drops out. I do understand the reason for this.

When I say `startyear=2016` and `startmonth=1`, I mean starting from 1st month of 2016, so 12th month of both years has to be in the result. Couldn't find anything helpful online, is there a way to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where clause is wrong. You need to handle the first and last year separately, example:

```
var result = balances
    .Where(x => 
        x.Year == startYear && x.Month >= startMonth ||
        x.Year > startYear && x.Year < endYear ||
        x.Year == endYear && x.Month <= endMonth);
```

To explain the logic, you want all items where:

- year is start year AND month is greater than start month

**OR**

- year is greater than start year AND year is lesser than end year

**OR**

- year is end year AND month is lesser than end month